# Filter for specific content in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been learning about filter and show content in my page, right now I add a `<select>` element to make the search so I based the function of the select element in my function from the text input and Works fine, check the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bu8safw/1/) but if I want to use the select to filter just the part of `Category: something` that is this part of the code `<span class="pull-right category">` **How can I do it?**.

Right now if I choose the option `Fisrt` in the dropdownlist shows me the first and third panel because in the third `panel-body` content exist the word First so I want to point just to the content of the class `category` from my span element and show the panels with `First` as category not in any other part of the panel.

**EDIT:** Basically I need to filter with the dropdowlinst by select the category and shows only the panel with the category I choose no matter the other content of the panel, just the `Category` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your filter, look for the term only within the span with the class *category* rather then the entire text of the panel.

Change:

```
$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

to

```
$(this).find('span.category').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).find(".category").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
```